# Excel VBA Borders

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to add a border to a series of cells that are being picked out by a Loop and nested If statement that I have in VBA in Excel.  Thing is, the only way I know of is to add an Underline statement to the code, but my teacher is wanting me to do a bottom border.  Thing is, after trying a trick that was mentioned here on StackOverflow, I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.  Can someone help?

```
Sub InputTitle()
'Subrutine's title is off from the actual task being performed.
'Excel asks user for a title to be input below.
Dim strTitle As String
strTitle = InputBox("Please enter a title")
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = strTitle & " Library Budget"
Range("B4").Select

'Excel goes through the cells, searching for the value 'Net Budget'.
'If Excel finds the value as Total, it will add a bottom border to
'the subsiquent cells, before continuing the loop.
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "Net Budget:"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Total:" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1:D1").Select
        <<--Selection.Border (xlEdgeBottom)-->>
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

I know there's a line of code that has '<<-- -->>'.  That's there for identification purposes as to what I'm aiming to do.  Each time I run the code, the system faults at that line, telling me, 'Object does not support this property or method'.  Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?  I get the feeling it's overly basic, and it's me looking more like an idiot than anything else...

Comment: the easiest way to find how to apply bottom border is to use [macro recorder](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html).

Comment: It's failing on that line because <<-- isn't valid VBA syntax.

Comment: @roryap I understand that's not a valid syntax because I used that to help point out where it's faulting.  I didn't put it there when I was first creating and editing the code in VBA.  That's only there to show the line that the syntax is faulting at.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `<<--Selection.Border (xlEdgeBottom)-->>` with `Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous`.

What simoco said is true: if you record a macro, you can then look at the code to see what it's doing.

Comment: Yeah, I should have did that with the macro. XD  Now I just feel goofy.